# Properly specifying php include/require paths

Tags: php, pdo

Using two different php files with very different paths on a host machine: `api.php` and `api2.php`, How can one use an include statement to freely use all the code in `api2.php` in `api.php`. The path of the api2.php file that should be included is `Desktop > PushChatServer > Api`. The path for the `api.php` file is `Desktop > HtDocs > Folder1` Is this how one would correctly specify an include/require path in the `api.php` file to successfully use the data from `api2.php`?

```
require_once 'Desktop/PushChatServer/api2.php';
```

Or would the following work though both files have different paths?

```
require_once 'api2.php';
```

Source: `Files are included based on the file path given or, if none is given, the include_path specified.` http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php

I want o make sure the script reads the right path. Is it possible to use this type of path in a require statement?

Comment: "I was wondering if it would be possible to use a php include statement to use the variables from the latter file in the first file?" Yes. Clearly you know this statement exists, have you run into troubles using it?

Comment: Yes, the program threw an exception at the time of $_POST. I was just wondering if the fact that the files had a different path had something to do with it. I was also wondering how to properly format the require statement and how much code to bring over from file to file to get it working.

Comment: any code relevant to the question must be included in the question.

Comment: So miken32, even though these files have different paths, if I add a require statement at the top of api.php, I will be able to use all the variables from api2.php where ever I want?

Comment: You don't want a variable, you want the result of a function, which, yes, you can call if it's included. I suggest deleting this question and heading over to [the PHP manual for `include`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php). You aren't going to get an answer here, and will only be losing rep to downvotes.

Comment: You're helping out a ton, thank you. While the question is still live I'd like to ask a question based of a sentence in the link you posted: "Files are included based on the file path given" ... since I want to include the api2.php file and it's is located in Desktop > Pushchatserver > Api , would you be able to help me verify the correct path to include? That would answer my question; you could also post it in a new answer if you want. I just want to make sure the path is right. +1

Comment: It's best to specify the full path to the file. `require(/where/is/this/file.php);`

Comment: also, use require and not require_once unless you really, really need to. require_once has much more overhead because it needs to check if it's "once" or not

Comment: Thank you @MichaelClark I am glad I kept this question alive. Can you take a look at the second part of this question I just asked? I'm looking for specifics http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35077418/choosing-the-right-path-in-a-require-statement/35077509#35077509

Comment: An absolute path takes some of the guesswork out of things and is a solid reference, because PHP is a preprocessor, relative paths can get hairy or impossible. For something simple, a relative path is fine though.

What you're looking for is the Server Side Path, and every host will do it differently. It looks to me like yours will be something like this, assuming that /api is your root folder for your domain, that's what your documentation was indicating.

/Users/matthijs/Desktop/PushChatServer/api/[[the path from there]]

It may take a bit of trial and error, but you'll find it.

Answer (score -1):

To get the exact path of the file you're using open it in Text Wrangler (free for download). Once the file is opened in text wrangler go to where it says `copy path` and you can then pick a multitude of options ranging from copy the url (text wrangler will generate one for your file) or copy full path (text wrangler will generate the full path). In my case it was this

`require  'file://localhost/Users/user/Desktop/PushChatServer/api/api.php';`