# Choosing the right path in a require statement

Tags: php, mysql, apache

How would one generate a successful `php` require statement path if the two files being joined have different directories? I want to be able to be able to use all of the data in one file in another. The file I want to include/require is located in `desktop > pushchatserver > api > api.php`. When setting up the local server I had to put the paths of pushchatservers contents in the `Applications/MAMP/conf/apache/httpd.conf` file like this so the server could reach it.
 [image]

```
 //This will be the require statement located in the php file that wants to use the data from api.php

require("/What/should/the/path/be?/api.php");
```

Also, if it helps, this is the url that the app uses to communicate with pushchatserver's contents at run-time `#define ServerApiURL @"http://192.168.1.5:44447/api.php"` My question : Would that url work as a path? There seem to be a lot of different options. Does anyone know which path will be successful for this type of require statement?

Answer (score 2):

The require path is always relative to the list of directories defined in the include_path ini file setting. Hence you would not usually end up with a full path but rather a relative path from the include_path value. Note that you can set the include_path setting in PHP from within the httpd.conf file if you like similarly to what you have done with the php_flag setting in your example.

I can barely read your screen shot but I think the spoon-feeding answer is:

add this line to your apache config:

```
php_value "include_path"  "/Users/ratthijs/Desktop/PushChatServer/api"
```

And then you could just say:

```
require_once('api.php');
```

Comment: the city needs you, help me out here.